# how to find specific and support vector machine

Tags: kernel, svm

I have listened to many lectures about SVM and kernel trick, but I am not sure how to find which kernel to use and what the parameters will be. Do you find the parameters using gradient method? I know what kernel does, but how do you choose which kernel to use and how many?

Answer (score 0):

The parameters are generally a problem of model selection. So for that I would advice to go with cross validation. As far as the kernel is concerned, we want to choose a kernel which would minimize the test error without overfitting the data. For instance, the high-degree polynomial is likely to overfit the data. We can choose RBF/gaussian kernel. They are used when the voundary is very complex. In small sample setting, you should use simple classifier/kernel because of scissor's effect. You can also read more on:

[Support Vector Machine kernel types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33778297/support-vector-machine-kernel-types)